# Delete/remove/drop variable in q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I've created a variable in the :

```
q)myvar: 1
```

How can I delete it?
I've tried:

```
q)delete myvar from `.z
```

but the namespace `.z is clearly not the right one, as the variable still does exist:

```
q)myvar
1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The top namespace is actually called `` `. ``, so the following will work:

```
q)delete myvar from `.
`.
q)myvar
`myvar
```

Also, running `` key `. `` will show all variable defined in the top namespace.